# Sharepoint Date Formatting Tracker JSON

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, json

I’m creating a currency tracker in sharepoint and want to add some coloured date formatting.

My parameters are the following:

- Expired including today ( #ff7676)
- Expiring in the next 2 months (#ffcf76)
- More than 2 months (none)

I’ve tested a few other scripts and none of them have had the required outcome. Posted below.

Appreciate any help! Thanks!

Test 1:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "@currentField",
  "style": {
    "background-color": "=if(@currentField >= @now + 2678400000 || @currentField <= @now - 62208000000,'none', '#ffcf76')"
  }
}
```

Test 2:

```
    {
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "=if([$DueDate]>(@now +10368000000), 'Green', if([$DueDate]>@now && [$DueDate]< (@now +10368000000), 'Expiring', 'Expired'))",
  "style": {
    "background-color": "=if([$DueDate]>(@now +10368000000), 'Green', if([$DueDate]>@now && [$DueDate]< (@now +10368000000), 'Orange', 'Red'))",
    "color": "black",
    "font-size": "1.5em",
    "justify-content": "center"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check as following:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "@currentField",
  "style": {
    "background-color": "=if(@currentField <=@now,'#ff7676',if(@currentField <=@now+5184000000 && @currentField>@now,'#ffcf76',if(@currentField>@now+5184000000,'','')"
  }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Julie. Works perfectly!

Comment: Remember to mark the reply as answer if it helps you, which will be beneficial to other community members reading this thread.